# Как делается такой блок?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Есть кнопка в футере (правая нижняя), по нажатию которой появляется subscribe-окошко. Обращаю внимание, что происходит выравнивание по правому краю кнопки. Насколько я понимаю, это не модальное окно. Прошу подсказать метод реализации, в каком направлении двигаться. Я подумал было, что сделать его можно табами, но что-то засомневался.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: банальный show/hide или fade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $('.mes').hide();
  $('.but').on('click', function() {
    $('.mes').toggle(100);;
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.p {
  height: 2500px;
}
.mes {
  background-color: #fc9;
  border: 3px solid #f93;
  bottom: 25px;
  height: 200px;
  left: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
}
.but {
  color: white;
  background-color: #ffab33;
  width: 300px;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.cont {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="p">Простыня</div>
<div class="cont">
  <div class="but">Подписаться</div>
  <div class="mes">Подписка. Форма ниже</div>
</div>
```